# How to get data from dynamic table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I will receive data from some IOT with a JSON data. Each IOT can send different data with different structure.

I created a MYSQL script to import my data in my database.

My table data_root is like a index who refer to different tables with the content to get.

I didn't know columns of my tables likes 'relay' or 'thrusters'.
In my table data_root, I inserted the 'table_name'  to know which table I need to question.

Tables that I want to question, have an id_data in references to the data table.

Mysql schemas:
[image]

I want to create Mysql Query to get data from thrusters for example or relay but without knowing their columns.

My SQL query :

```
SELECT data.id_data , data.timestamp, data_root.table_name, data_root.table_name_id
FROM data, data_root, thrusters
WHERE data.id_data = data_root.id_data
AND data.id_data = thrusters.id_data
AND data.code_transmetteur = 1
GROUP BY thrusters.id
```

Which method can I use to get data from thrusters or relay with my schema.

Thanks for your helps,

Comment: `SELECT thrusters.* ...` ?

Comment: This is questionable... I doubt that a relational database is a good choice for data of unknown structure. Either you want to store the specific data in JSON format which removes the constraint to have separate tables, or you want to use a no sql database which is much better in handling arbitrary structured data.

Comment: SELECT thrusters.* work fine :D

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL 8.0.11 or newer, then you have a few options:

- create columns containing JSON and save them as you get them
- use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to do queries on JSON-strings
- use any of the [JSON_SEARCH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)-functions to check what you received and extract the data

In your case it sounds like you should use JSON_SEARCH to check what kind of object you are getting and then JSON_TABLE to properly import it.